Angular application getting random 504 errors from .NET server (both Azure App Service)
My Angular application is getting random 504 errors when requesting various endpoints of my backend server (.NET).
Technical stack :

Backend : .NET 8
Frontend : Angular 16+ with Serverside rendering and progressive web app enabled
Authorization : JWT
Database : PostgreSQL
Hosting : Both front and backend are hosted on linux production plan app services

Why random ?

The same endpoint can be hit without errors from the same/different user at another moment during the day
My backend server is serving successfully lots of requests at the same time other users get the 504 errors.
Sometime my users have 504 errors and sometime they get CORS errors like Access to fetch at 'https://my-backend-server/endpoint' from origin 'https://my-frontend-app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

What did I try ?

.NET : Change CORS configuration to .AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
.NET : Add .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true) on my CORS policy
Azure : Scale-up my App Services
Angular : Add an RxJS timeout on my HttpInterceptor (the one I use to inject my JWToken) : return next.handle(request).pipe(timeout(this._defaultTimeout));
Angular : Add ApplicationInsights both on my App Services to better troubleshoot the errors (now I exactly know that a lot of users get these errors everyday )
Angular : Improve my <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" tag to include all external calls in every possible section
Azure : Disable CORS on both my App Services (crashed the apps)

For information, I did not find any pattern on the failed requests (GET, POST), with or without authentication/authorization, during the day or low activity periods (~10pm), different controllers, etc.
EDIT - Adding Program.cs - CORS configuration
// Defines CORS policy
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicyName,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true);
        });
});
...
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors(CorsPolicyName);
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...

I simplified CORS policy to allow everything to troubleshoot if it was coming from this. Previously i was using .WithOrigins([.. AllowedOrigins]) where AllowedOrigins is a List<string> containing my frontend app service origins / azure functions / external partners using our backend.
My CORS configuration in Azure : 
All urls match frontend app service or external partners.

Seems there are 2 errors in your application, please following my steps to enable logging feature, hope we can find more details.

The second, you should share your code in the Program.cs with us, we need to check the cors setting and middleware order. Please hide your sensitive information if have.

Hi @JasonPan thanks for your comment, i edited my message to include Program.cs configuration and my technical stack. I dont have the same configuration but my logging is enabled on both my frontend and backend app services with AppInsights

Hi Sylions, CORS middleware should be after app.UseRouting();.

Do you think this can cause the mentioned errors ? Why would it be so random ?

Maybe, I am not sure, the cors may caused by other middlewares, you should enable asp.net core middleware logging feature first, it can help us find more.

OK i switched CORS and other middlewares order to respect MS guidance. We'll see how it works with that. I will try to improve logging as well. Thanks for helping :)

@Sylions - Is your issue resolved?

HI @Harshitha we are facing less and less errors since we did two actions :


switch HTTP protocol in our app services from 2 to 1.1 due to reported issue here


change order of our middlewares to respect MS guidance
We are now investigating the remaining 504 errors to see if it's still problematic.
Do you also have that kind of errors or do you have any advice on this issue ?



Does your app has any DB configuration?

yes we are using Postgre with EntityFramework why ?

Hope you have configured the required DB for the Deployed app?
